# Unable to add WAS 8.5 in RSA 9.1

Tags: server, websphere, rational-rsa

I am unable to add Websphere (WAS) 8.5 in Rational Software Architect (RSA) 9.1 from New->Server in Rational Software Architect. It is asking for Installation Directory. I am not getting which path I have to give.
I tried in giving some random path, and error message gets popup 'The WebSphere Application Server installation directory is not correct.' Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.1.2/com.ibm.servertools.doc/topics/twcrtins_v6.html) helpful.  RSA is prompting you for the installation root of the app server.  The default location for Linux is /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/, for Windows C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer.

Comment: (And, of course, you must have a copy of WebSphere installed there)

Answer (score 0):

I had install RSA 9.1 but not WAS 8.5. Because of this, this issue is persisting.
After installing WAS8.5, we can give path C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer in the installation directory and hence can create new server.